# optaplanner kie workbench 7.0 multiple entities support

Tags: optaplanner

is there a way to solve a problem with multiple planning entities each of them with one planning variable within the workbench (7.0) ?

In fact what I ask is there a way in the solver configuration (editor) to set two different construction heuristics, one per planning entity and then have a union local search (unionmoveselector) as you deal with multiple planning entities in optaplanner ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 7.0, the solver editor screen does not yet allow power tweaking the move selector of the Construction Heuristic. In any case, with the optaplanner-core for 7.1, it is easier to power tweak those on the core side, which will make it somewhat easier to expose them on the workbench side at some point in the future.